# text underline display none after animation, fade out effect not working

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

I am trying to do an effect using CSS. I am doing a React.Js page and I want the title to slide in with two favicon wheels underneath faking a truck. The title has an underline text. The animation brings the title with the spinning wheels from the left and finish in the center, then the wheels fade out using @keyframes opacity, but it doesnt work with the underline in the text. I just wanted to be smooth the fade out as the wheels. Here below is my code.

This is the JS:

```
<div className={styles.header}>
              <div className={styles.animationFadeOut}>
                <p className={`${styles.title} ${styles.titleAnimation}`}>TiziFlet<br />
                <span className={styles.borderTopIcon}>
                  <GiCarWheel size="0.8em" color='#3c3c3c' className={`${styles.iconClass1} ${styles.wheelAnimation}`}  />
                  <GiCarWheel size="0.8em" color='#3c3c3c' className={`${styles.iconClass2} ${styles.wheelAnimation}`}  />
                </span></p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 1vh;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.title {
  color: #e95454;
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  /* text-decoration: underline #e95454; */
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #6e9abe, 2px 2px 4px #000000;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.title:hover {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #6e9abe, 2px 2px 3px #ffffff;
}
.iconClass1 {
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.iconClass2 {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.borderTopIcon {
  border-top-color: #e95454;
  border-top-width: 4px;
}
span .wheelAnimation {
  animation-name: wheels;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  
}
@keyframes wheels {
  0% {transform: rotate(0)}
  90% {transform: rotate(720deg); display: block; opacity: 1;}
  100% {transform: rotate(900deg); display: none; opacity: 0;}
}
div .titleAnimation {
  animation-name: tizi;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  transition: 8s;
}
@keyframes tizi {
  0% {left: -1000px; text-decoration: underline;}
  90% {left: 0px; text-decoration: underline;}
  98% {left: 0px; text-decoration: none;}
  100% {left: 0px; text-decoration: none;}
}
```

It is the first time I use @keyframes, if there is someone that can help me would be great! Thanks

Comment: You can't animate the underline that way. You have to use another div or pseudo element  and animate its width from 0 to 100%. The underline property has only 2 states, it doesn't work the way you want it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is too specific to have any value for other users (but uses keywords that more generally applicable questions also use)